# Strip {...} or [...] from string using TRegEx

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-xe3

I have the following functions, which should remove all occurrences of (...), [...] and {...} in a string

```
function TCleanUp.DoStripBraces(const aInput: string): string; // works!
begin
  result := TRegEx.Replace(aInput, '\([^)]*\)', '');
end;

function TCleanUp.DoStripCurlyBraces(const aInput: string): string; // does not work
begin
  result := TRegEx.Replace(aInput, '\{[^\}]*}', '');
end;

function TCleanUp.DoStripSquareBrackets(const aInput: string): string; // does not work
begin
  result := TRegEx.Replace(aInput, '\[[^\]]*]', '');
end;
```

I'm testing the functions with these strings

```
'foo (bar) baz (xyz)'
'foo [bar] baz [xyz]'
'foo {bar} baz {xyz}'
```

which all should return the following string

```
'foo  baz '
```

When I use the same strings and expressions on http://www.regexr.com/ it matches the occurrences perfectly.

I also tried to not escape the bracket / curly brace in the character set, but that did not work either.

How can I make the expressions work?

Comment: Do you have any nesting?

Comment: I'm writing a general purpose Text Processor, so I don't really know the input.

Comment: What makes you believe that a regex can work in full generality

Comment: Nothing in particular, but I think it will work better than any algorithm I can come up with in limited time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a one regex like this:

```
[([{].*?[)}\]]
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM3qQ4/3)**

On the other hand, if you want to have 3 separated regex you can use:

```
\(.*?\)
\[.*?\]
\{.*?\}
```

Putting them altogether, you can see what they match:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

These regexes above are more readable than have:

```
\([^)]*?\)     As you can see, this is error prone as you faced. 
\[[^\]]*?\]
\{[^}]*?\}
```

Although, the disadvantage of this readability impacts a little on the performance. Using `.*?` is slower than use `[^...]*` but unless you have to parse really long strings you won't notice the difference.

You can see the difference visually:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: nice, I'm gonna use the 3 separated expressions. I didn't know you could combine the quantifiers to do this.

Comment: @Gloegg just for you to know, the usage of those quantifiers to make a regex from greedy to lazy. For instance if you have `a*b` it will match greedily `aaabab` in the string `aaabab`, but if you have `a*?b` it will match lazily `aaab`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to escape the latest occurrences of `]` and `}`.

Try `'\{[^\}]*\}'` and `'\[[^\]]*\]'`.

Comment: the closing ] and } don't need to be escaped, since they are only considered special characters when they are with an opening [ or { (but it doesn't harm to escape them nonetheless)

Comment: Oh, ok, didn't know that. I was just giving an answer based on experience of other regex types.